# How to backup (automatically) an azure sql database on a local server?

Tags: azure-sql-database, backup-sqldatabase

I am looking for a way to backup an azure sql database to a local server. The backup should be created automatically.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `BACKUP` - since Azure SQL Database is always a newer version than any other version of SQL Server that you can install.

The way to do this is to extract a BACPAC and then apply that to your local server

If you want the local copy to be updated regularly - but not continuously, AND the local copy does not get updated, then consider [Azure Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a recommendation on how to extract a BACPAC and apply that to a local server automatically?

Comment: I'd do this with PowerShell and schedule it from the local server.  Install DBA Tools modules to make your life a bit easier as well. You will extract it out to an Azure Storage Blob, download it and then load it locally using sqlpackage.exe